# Extra new lines in Plain text email via SendGrid

Tags: c#, email, azure, sendgrid

I am using a standard .NET SMTPClient to send a PLAIN text email - as follows:

```
// Configure mail client
using (SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient(AppConfig.SMTPServer))
   {
            mailClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(AppConfig.SMTPUsername, AppConfig.SMTPPassword);

            // Create the mail message
            MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();

            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(AppConfig.SMTPSenderEmail, AppConfig.SMTPSenderDisplay);

            foreach (string recipient in recipients)
            {
                mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(recipient));
            }

            mailMessage.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(AppConfig.SMTPBC));
            mailMessage.Subject = subject;
            mailMessage.Body = body;
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = false;

            // Attachments
            if (attachments != null && attachments.Any())
            {
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Byte[]> attachment in attachments)
                {
                    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(attachment.Value);
                    mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(memStream, attachment.Key));
                }
            }

            mailClient.Send(mailMessage);

        }
```

When sending through a POP3 client the email that is sent has the expected format, *however* when I send through the `Azure SendGrid module`, each new line is doubled up so there are two blank lines for every one in the source body string. Does anyone know how to circumvent this issue as I need (and want) to use SendGrid.

I see this very similar question [SendGrid newline issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276181/extra-newlines-in-plain-text-emails-sent-via-sendgrid) however the fix relates to PHP - I need the equivalent in C#

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, after several hours of investigation, within 5 minutes of posting the question I find the answer and its real simple, adding this to the mail client configuration sorts the issue perfectly:

```
mailMessage.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```